# How to trigger spinning wheel diagnostics report

Tags: performance, vmware, macos

I'm working on application that consume significant CPU time and memory under heavy load.

my setup configuration is fusion VM that runs macOS Sierra 10.12.6.

At some stage I get spinning wheel and the entire VM hangs. Unfortunately I couldn't find any valuable log after rebooting the machine.

perhaps there's a way to enforce taking performance diagnostics report so that I could properly analyze what cause the hanging ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name for the "spinning wheel" or "spinning beachball" is actually called the ***spinning wait cursor,***  similar to the hourglass on Windows machines.

There's no diagnostic report that's associated with a wait cursor because it only appears if there is more than 2 seconds of delay.

To find out what is slowing down your system, use Activity Monitor.

Comment: so what should I do in order to analyze this scenario .. what log files should I look for after rebooting that may hint the root cause ?

Comment: unfortunately, I cannot run activity monitor when I get the spinning wait cursor since the system is hanged.

Comment: It should be running *prior* to the start, not after.  Remember, logs only get created when an error occurs and and something is written to them. If you entire system is hung, even the logging process will be affected.

Comment: You can also look into `dtrace` - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/CreatingCustomInstruments.html - unfortunately, this level of development is outside my scope.

Comment: Check out this blog for some useful scripts:  http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/