# How to restore default user permissions (MacOS 13 Ventura)

Tags: macos, mac, finder, permission

### Background

I have 3 Macs at home, all running MacOS 13 Ventura. All of these Macs are running on relatively new computers but the systems have been passed on via Migration Assistant/Time Machine backups since the beginning of the ~2010s (OSX Snow Leopard & Lion).

I recently discovered the user permissions on these Macs probably are wrong (i.e they are not the default permissions). I'm not sure why that is, but it may be that I changed things due to ignorance far back in the past, or migrations, etc, may have altered things.

Rationale: I'm concerned for security & functional reasons even though I am currently unaware of direct issues with these Macs due to my permissions.

NB: I did recently have File Sharing problems in Ventura 13 which was previously mentioned in this question, but was a SMB bug now resolved with Ventura 13.3 ([source](https://www.macrumors.com/2023/03/23/macos-13-3-fixes-network-file-sharing/)).

### Question

**Should I, and if so, how can I restore or apply Apple default user permissions, without having to erase my systems and recreate them from scratch? (Assuming that this is a good idea?)**

SIP is activated, and as mentioned I am running the latest MacOS version as of February, 2023 – therefore many old Ask Different answers may not apply.

---

### Additional info

On one of my Macs, I created a new administrator user (named *test*) to see what the default permissions are for common Home folders. **WARNING**: I can't guarantee that these are correct for an entirely fresh system, this is just what I happen to see on a new user on a non-factory restored Mac – please do not attempt to replicate:

- **Mac #1**

  - *test* (New test user):

    - `~` (Home folder `test`)

      - test (me): Read & Write
      - staff: Read only
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`, `~/Library`:

      - test (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Library`:

      - test (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Public`:

      - test (me): Read & Write
      - staff: Read only
      - everyone: Read only
    - `Macintosh HD/Applications`

      - system: Read & Write
      - admin: Read & Write
      - everyone: Read only
      - **NOTE**: These `Applications` groups look strange to me. Since they are shared by all users on the computer it's possible that they aren't the default Apple permissions. My other Mac does instead of ***system: Read & Write*** and ***admin: Read & Write***, have ***user (me): Read & Write*** and ***staff: Read only***.

Following are settings on my actively in-use accounts on my Macs.

Noteworthy: in some folders I see peculiar users called: *com.apple.sharepoint.group.1* *com.apple.sharepoint.group.2*, *com.apple.sharepoint.group.3*, and *Fetching…* (a spinning wait cursor and contents that don't load) – these have "Custom" permissions!

- **Mac #1**

  - *user* (Old user):

    - `~` (Home folder `user`)

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - staff: Read only
      - everyone: Read only **(No Access on *test*)**
    - `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: Read only **(No Access on *test*)**
    - `~/Library`:

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Public`:

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - **staff: Does not exist at all (staff: Read only on *test*)**
      - everyone: Read only
    - `Macintosh HD/Applications`

      - system: Read & Write
      - admin: Read & Write
      - everyone: Read only
- **Mac #2**

  - *user* (Old user):

    - `~` (Home folder `user`)

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - staff: Read only
      - everyone: Read only **(No Access on *test*)**
    - `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - staff: Read only **(staff does not exist here on *test*)**
      - everyone: Read only **(No Access on *test*)**
    - `~/Library`:

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Public`:

      - com.apple.sharepoint.group.1: Custom **(I don't know what this is!)**
      - user (me): Read & Write
      - **staff: Does not exist at all (staff: Read only on *test*)**
      - everyone: No Access **(Read only on *test*)**
    - `Macintosh HD/Applications`

      - system: Read & Write
      - admin: Read & Write
      - everyone: Read only
- **Mac #3**

  - *user* (Old user):

    - `~` (Home folder `user`)

      - com.apple.sharepoint.group.2: Custom **(I don't know what this is!)**
      - *Fetching…*: Custom **(I don't know what this is. Doesn't load properly – shows a spinning wait cursor!)**
      - user (me): Read & Write
      - **staff: Does not exist at all (staff: Read only on *test*)**
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Desktop`, `~/Documents`, `~/Downloads`

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: Read only **(No Access on *test*)**
    - `~/Library`:

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - everyone: No Access
    - `~/Public`:

      - user (me): Read & Write
      - **staff: Does not exist at all (staff: Read only on *test*)**
      - everyone: Read only
    - `Macintosh HD/Applications`

      - user (me): Read & Write **(Does not exist on *test*. system: Read only exists instead)**
      - staff: Read only **(Does not exist on *test*. admin: Read only exists instead)**
      - everyone: Read only

---

##### Edit: More Additional info

Some additional information after the original post.

On "Mac #3" above, when attempting to share my Home (`~`) folder specifically (**System Settings > Sharing > File Sharing > ℹ️ > Shared Folders**), I see the following:

- Unknown User: Custom
- Unknown User: Custom
- Unknown User: Custom
- Unknown User: Custom
- My user (me): Read & Write
- Everyone: No Access

Related to the "Unknown Users" is probably the endlessly spinning wait cursor for the "Get Info" permissions on the Home (`~`) folder *[my user is truncated from the screenshot, but it has Read & Write, and Everyone has No Access]*:

[image]

If I try to share the `~/Downloads` folder specifically, I instead see this in File Sharing:

- Downloads: Custom
- Discord Data: Custom ("Discord Data" is a folder in Downloads)
- Downloads: Custom
- Downloads: Custom
- My user (me): Read & Write
- Everyone: No Access

And the Get Info permissions below *[my user is truncated from the screenshot, but it has Read & Write, and Everyone has No Access]*:

[image]

Comment: This statement stands out as most important (IMO):  *the user permissions on these Macs probably are wrong*. "Probably wrong?" How did you determine they are "wrong" to begin with?  Second most, the disclaimer you make, *I can't guarantee that these are correct for...* is very concerning!  ***If you want to change permissions across several Mac computers and you're not certain if there's actually a bona fide problem, you could  err here and break things quite epically***.  Have you tried running Disk Utility First Aid, *first*?

Comment: @Allan Not following your logic. They are *probably* wrong because they likely do not conform to what defaults are, which is a reasonable suspicion. I did not say that they *are* wrong. Guidance on what to do is what I'm seeking from Ask Different. I inserted a disclaimer because I do not want other users to replicate my settings, the purpose of which is the opposite of creating concern.

Comment: @Allan I am aware that changing things without bona fide problem is problematic, however, there is a File Sharing issue as described. I've run Disk Utility First Aid, and it did not mention anything about system permission errors.

Comment: That "file sharing issue" is likely not related to permissions.  The "spinning wheel" is called a [wait cursor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303966/119271).  If you're getting this, it means that *something* isn't responding.  If it were a permission issue, you'd be able to see the file, but not write to it (with Read Only access, for example).  This is definately an  [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Allan It may be an "XY Problem", but why is it "definitely" an XY Problem and not an actual issue e.g. wrt permission security? Put differently: if you look at the user permissions I've described – do they look feasibly correct to you? That must be the case, because if they are visibly incorrect/unsafe/likely to cause issues, etc, then I think it is misleading for you to suggest to otherwise. I would appreciate technical clarity on this issue before questioning the issue on philosophical basis.

Comment: It’s XY because the problem is the poor performance, but you’re focusing on permissions, something you have a firmer grasp of.  For technical clarity, when you (or family members) log in to any of the Mac computers, do do you have issues accessing files and preventing unauthorized users from accessing what they are not supposed to? ?   If not, then it isn’t permissions problem because permission are the same whether local or remote. The spinning wait cursor means the system hasn’t responded to a call.

Comment: @Allan The file problem is not exactly poor performance – that is that folders load instantaneously but files therein take indefinitely long time to display (they never display), i.e. there is no "performance" at all, which is why I suspected permission issues for files. Whether unauthorized users can access files is unknown (that by itself does not affect whether hazard exists or not, i.e. known unknowns vs. unknown unknowns).

Comment: @Allan The question here is: why are the permissions so disparate over these systems, and if this is indicative of a messy and problematic setup – how does one resolve it? Are you able to address this question technically? For example, are you saying that migrations and various software events over the years frequently give rise to non-conforming permissions? If so, that would explain a lot. I am interested in such technical Q&A, more so than musings about what is a bad question. The core issue has not been adressed so far, however interesting the surrounding landscape.

Comment: I asked if you had actual issues with permissions.  I also asked if you ran First Aid.

Comment: @Allan Are widely disparate permissions on systems something normal to be expected?

Comment: You have only shown POSIX permissions. Some directories (Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Library, Pictures, Public) also have an ACL: "group:everyone deny delete"

Answer (score 1):

This answer is pointers, not a detailed solution, to resetting permissions.

Howard Oakley (Electic Light Company) has, at least twice, discussed the mysteries of resetting home folder permissions:

Some years old, but essential reading: [Something odd you can’t fix? Sierra re-introduces repairing permissions](https://eclecticlight.co/2017/06/15/something-odd-you-cant-fix-sierra-re-introduces-repairing-permissions/)

More recent: [Repairing Home folder permissions: a mystery](https://eclecticlight.co/2022/11/18/repairing-home-folder-permissions-a-mystery/)

Why 'mystery'? Because this is not properly documented by Apple and uses commands not mentioned in any `man` page.

Try using `diskutil resetUserPermissions` which will give your brief usage instructions.  Also the Recovery mode command `repairHomePermissions`. Both are undocumented and there is some uncertainly regarding exactly what they change!

I have not used either of these and, if you do, make sure you have a backup and recovery plan in case of disaster.