# I switched my System Photo Library and now it seems locked up with an endless beach ball!

Tags: macos, icloud, photos, library

Back story:
I have iCloud Photos turned on.

I changed my photos settings from the “optimize storage” setting, to the “keep original copies on this computer” setting.

This change initiated a download from iCloud of all my photos to my hard drive. After 3 days the photos app paused the download—due to not enough system storage.

I closed photos. Went to my photos library and copied it to an external hard drive.

Once the copy was complete. I double clicked the new photos library to open the photos app and set this as the new photos library.

When photos opened I chose “use as system photo library” then the pinwheel came up and has been spinning for a few hours now!!

Should I wait and let it keep working?  If so, how long?

Comment: The spinning pin wheel is called a [wait cursor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/303966/119271) indicating that the system is waiting for something to finish.  If it doesn’t free up after a few moments, your app is hung.  Kill it and restart.